# Is there a way to by pass "Auto Start" in MI Devices to run background services in android?

Tags: android, mi

Im making an android app which uses background services to show price comparisons when a user visits detail page of the respective site i.e flipkart.

There are few apps which are doing this like [Fairbuy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fairbuy.allinoneshoppingapp.compareprice.bestprice.wishlist.flipkartsale.amazonindia) app which allows users to compare prices of products they view in apps/browsers in sites like amazon, flipkart etc. Even fairbuy needs auto start permission to keep a background service running to detect which product is viewed etc.

Is there a way to bypass Auto Start permission in Mi Devices to keep background services running? Getting a pemission is difficult and its very difficult to tell users why we need this permission.

Comment: There is no official documented way .. You can only call an intent to let use lend on auto-start setting screen ..and Pray that they will turn it on . And you certainly can not By pass it also..

Comment: Is there a way to get a call back and check if the auto start has been enabled by user?

Comment: There isn't one